# Error : Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

```
Future<List<Dashboard>> _getDashboard() async {
    print(parameters.toString());
    var response = await http.post(API.get_dashboard2, body: parameters);
    var dashboard = json.decode(response.body);
    var _dashboards = dashboard['success'];

    if (_dashboards == 1) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        for (listJson in dashboard) {
          _list.add(Dashboard.fromJson(listJson));
        }
      }
    } else if (_dashboards == 0) {
      Toast.show(dashboard['message'], context,
          gravity: Toast.BOTTOM, duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
  }
```

My Json Response is:

```
{"order":[{"total_order":"14","o_cur_month":"0","o_per_month":"4"}],"customer":[{"total_customer":"12","c_cur_month":"0","c_per_month":"1"}],"pending":[{"total_pending_top":"5","total_pending_bottom":"2","cur_month_top":"0","cur_month_bottom":"0","per_month_top":"1","per_month_bottom":"1","six_month_top":"0","six_month_bottom":"0"}],"receiving":[{"total_rec_top":"9","total_rec_bottom":"5","cur_month_top":"0","cur_month_bottom":"0","per_month_top":"2","per_month_bottom":"2","average_sales_tops":"10.0000","average_sales_Bottoms":"6.0000"}],"success":1,"message":"Data Found"}
```

let me give you my Model Class that from that you can understand more properly

```
class Dashboard {
  List<Order> order;
  List<Customer> customer;
  List<Pending> pending;
  List<Receiving> receiving;
  int success;
  String message;

  Dashboard(
      {this.order,
        this.customer,
        this.pending,
        this.receiving,
        this.success,
        this.message});

  Dashboard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['order'] != null) {
      order = new List<Order>();
      json['order'].forEach((v) {
        order.add(new Order.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['customer'] != null) {
      customer = new List<Customer>();
      json['customer'].forEach((v) {
        customer.add(new Customer.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['pending'] != null) {
      pending = new List<Pending>();
      json['pending'].forEach((v) {
        pending.add(new Pending.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['receiving'] != null) {
      receiving = new List<Receiving>();
      json['receiving'].forEach((v) {
        receiving.add(new Receiving.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    success = json['success'];
    message = json['message'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.order != null) {
      data['order'] = this.order.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.customer != null) {
      data['customer'] = this.customer.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.pending != null) {
      data['pending'] = this.pending.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.receiving != null) {
      data['receiving'] = this.receiving.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['success'] = this.success;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    return data;
  }
}

class Order {
  String totalOrder;
  String oCurMonth;
  String oPerMonth;

  Order({this.totalOrder, this.oCurMonth, this.oPerMonth});

  Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    totalOrder = json['total_order'];
    oCurMonth = json['o_cur_month'];
    oPerMonth = json['o_per_month'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['total_order'] = this.totalOrder;
    data['o_cur_month'] = this.oCurMonth;
    data['o_per_month'] = this.oPerMonth;
    return data;
  }
}

class Customer {
  String totalCustomer;
  String cCurMonth;
  String cPerMonth;

  Customer({this.totalCustomer, this.cCurMonth, this.cPerMonth});

  Customer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    totalCustomer = json['total_customer'];
    cCurMonth = json['c_cur_month'];
    cPerMonth = json['c_per_month'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['total_customer'] = this.totalCustomer;
    data['c_cur_month'] = this.cCurMonth;
    data['c_per_month'] = this.cPerMonth;
    return data;
  }
}

class Pending {
  String totalPendingTop;
  String totalPendingBottom;
  String curMonthTop;
  String curMonthBottom;
  String perMonthTop;
  String perMonthBottom;
  String sixMonthTop;
  String sixMonthBottom;

  Pending(
      {this.totalPendingTop,
        this.totalPendingBottom,
        this.curMonthTop,
        this.curMonthBottom,
        this.perMonthTop,
        this.perMonthBottom,
        this.sixMonthTop,
        this.sixMonthBottom});

  Pending.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    totalPendingTop = json['total_pending_top'];
    totalPendingBottom = json['total_pending_bottom'];
    curMonthTop = json['cur_month_top'];
    curMonthBottom = json['cur_month_bottom'];
    perMonthTop = json['per_month_top'];
    perMonthBottom = json['per_month_bottom'];
    sixMonthTop = json['six_month_top'];
    sixMonthBottom = json['six_month_bottom'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['total_pending_top'] = this.totalPendingTop;
    data['total_pending_bottom'] = this.totalPendingBottom;
    data['cur_month_top'] = this.curMonthTop;
    data['cur_month_bottom'] = this.curMonthBottom;
    data['per_month_top'] = this.perMonthTop;
    data['per_month_bottom'] = this.perMonthBottom;
    data['six_month_top'] = this.sixMonthTop;
    data['six_month_bottom'] = this.sixMonthBottom;
    return data;
  }
}

class Receiving {
  String totalRecTop;
  String totalRecBottom;
  String curMonthTop;
  String curMonthBottom;
  String perMonthTop;
  String perMonthBottom;
  String averageSalesTops;
  String averageSalesBottoms;

  Receiving(
      {this.totalRecTop,
        this.totalRecBottom,
        this.curMonthTop,
        this.curMonthBottom,
        this.perMonthTop,
        this.perMonthBottom,
        this.averageSalesTops,
        this.averageSalesBottoms});

  Receiving.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    totalRecTop = json['total_rec_top'];
    totalRecBottom = json['total_rec_bottom'];
    curMonthTop = json['cur_month_top'];
    curMonthBottom = json['cur_month_bottom'];
    perMonthTop = json['per_month_top'];
    perMonthBottom = json['per_month_bottom'];
    averageSalesTops = json['average_sales_tops'];
    averageSalesBottoms = json['average_sales_Bottoms'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['total_rec_top'] = this.totalRecTop;
    data['total_rec_bottom'] = this.totalRecBottom;
    data['cur_month_top'] = this.curMonthTop;
    data['cur_month_bottom'] = this.curMonthBottom;
    data['per_month_top'] = this.perMonthTop;
    data['per_month_bottom'] = this.perMonthBottom;
    data['average_sales_tops'] = this.averageSalesTops;
    data['average_sales_Bottoms'] = this.averageSalesBottoms;
    return data;
  }
}
```

this is my Dashboard Model Class which will give you the fairly idea that when i went wrong and also please guide me through this difficult problem

I am new at this community so please take care of me

If there is any way that this json can be access through it then that would be great.

thank in advance.

Comment: Show the Dashboard class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use models/DTOs when working with JSON data to avoid such errors.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class DashboardModel {
  final List<Order>? order;
  final List<Customer>? customer;
  final List<Pending>? pending;
  final List<Receiving>? receiving;
  final int success;
  final String message;
  DashboardModel({
    required this.order,
    required this.customer,
    required this.pending,
    required this.receiving,
    required this.success,
    required this.message,
  });

  DashboardModel copyWith({
    List<Order>? order,
    List<Customer>? customer,
    List<Pending>? pending,
    List<Receiving>? receiving,
    int? success,
    String? message,
  }) {
    return DashboardModel(
      order: order ?? this.order,
      customer: customer ?? this.customer,
      pending: pending ?? this.pending,
      receiving: receiving ?? this.receiving,
      success: success ?? this.success,
      message: message ?? this.message,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'order': order?.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
      'customer': customer?.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
      'pending': pending?.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
      'receiving': receiving?.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
      'success': success,
      'message': message,
    };
  }

  factory DashboardModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return DashboardModel(
      order: List<Order>.from(
        List.from(map['order']).map(
          (x) => Order.fromMap(x),
        ),
      ),
      customer: List<Customer>.from(
        List.from(map['customer']).map(
          (x) => Customer.fromMap(x),
        ),
      ),
      pending: List<Pending>.from(
        List.from(map['pending']).map(
          (x) => Pending.fromMap(x),
        ),
      ),
      receiving: List<Receiving>.from(
        List.from(map['receiving']).map(
          (x) => Receiving.fromMap(x),
        ),
      ),
      success: map['success'],
      message: map['message'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory DashboardModel.fromJson(String source) =>
      DashboardModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class Order {
  final String total_order;
  final String o_cur_month;
  final String o_per_month;
  Order({
    required this.total_order,
    required this.o_cur_month,
    required this.o_per_month,
  });

  Order copyWith({
    String? total_order,
    String? o_cur_month,
    String? o_per_month,
  }) {
    return Order(
      total_order: total_order ?? this.total_order,
      o_cur_month: o_cur_month ?? this.o_cur_month,
      o_per_month: o_per_month ?? this.o_per_month,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'total_order': total_order,
      'o_cur_month': o_cur_month,
      'o_per_month': o_per_month,
    };
  }

  factory Order.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Order(
      total_order: map['total_order'],
      o_cur_month: map['o_cur_month'],
      o_per_month: map['o_per_month'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Order.fromJson(String source) => Order.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class Customer {
  final String total_customer;
  final String c_cur_month;
  final String c_per_month;
  Customer({
    required this.total_customer,
    required this.c_cur_month,
    required this.c_per_month,
  });

  Customer copyWith({
    String? total_customer,
    String? c_cur_month,
    String? c_per_month,
  }) {
    return Customer(
      total_customer: total_customer ?? this.total_customer,
      c_cur_month: c_cur_month ?? this.c_cur_month,
      c_per_month: c_per_month ?? this.c_per_month,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'total_customer': total_customer,
      'c_cur_month': c_cur_month,
      'c_per_month': c_per_month,
    };
  }

  factory Customer.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Customer(
      total_customer: map['total_customer'],
      c_cur_month: map['c_cur_month'],
      c_per_month: map['c_per_month'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Customer.fromJson(String source) =>
      Customer.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class Pending {
  final String total_pending_top;
  final String total_pending_bottom;
  final String cur_month_top;
  final String cur_month_bottom;
  final String per_month_top;
  final String per_month_bottom;
  final String six_month_top;
  final String six_month_bottom;
  Pending({
    required this.total_pending_top,
    required this.total_pending_bottom,
    required this.cur_month_top,
    required this.cur_month_bottom,
    required this.per_month_top,
    required this.per_month_bottom,
    required this.six_month_top,
    required this.six_month_bottom,
  });

  Pending copyWith({
    String? total_pending_top,
    String? total_pending_bottom,
    String? cur_month_top,
    String? cur_month_bottom,
    String? per_month_top,
    String? per_month_bottom,
    String? six_month_top,
    String? six_month_bottom,
  }) {
    return Pending(
      total_pending_top: total_pending_top ?? this.total_pending_top,
      total_pending_bottom: total_pending_bottom ?? this.total_pending_bottom,
      cur_month_top: cur_month_top ?? this.cur_month_top,
      cur_month_bottom: cur_month_bottom ?? this.cur_month_bottom,
      per_month_top: per_month_top ?? this.per_month_top,
      per_month_bottom: per_month_bottom ?? this.per_month_bottom,
      six_month_top: six_month_top ?? this.six_month_top,
      six_month_bottom: six_month_bottom ?? this.six_month_bottom,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'total_pending_top': total_pending_top,
      'total_pending_bottom': total_pending_bottom,
      'cur_month_top': cur_month_top,
      'cur_month_bottom': cur_month_bottom,
      'per_month_top': per_month_top,
      'per_month_bottom': per_month_bottom,
      'six_month_top': six_month_top,
      'six_month_bottom': six_month_bottom,
    };
  }

  factory Pending.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Pending(
      total_pending_top: map['total_pending_top'],
      total_pending_bottom: map['total_pending_bottom'],
      cur_month_top: map['cur_month_top'],
      cur_month_bottom: map['cur_month_bottom'],
      per_month_top: map['per_month_top'],
      per_month_bottom: map['per_month_bottom'],
      six_month_top: map['six_month_top'],
      six_month_bottom: map['six_month_bottom'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Pending.fromJson(String source) =>
      Pending.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class Receiving {
  final String total_rec_top;
  final String total_rec_bottom;
  final String cur_month_top;
  final String cur_month_bottom;
  final String per_month_top;
  final String per_month_bottom;
  final String average_sales_tops;
  final String average_sales_Bottoms;
  Receiving({
    required this.total_rec_top,
    required this.total_rec_bottom,
    required this.cur_month_top,
    required this.cur_month_bottom,
    required this.per_month_top,
    required this.per_month_bottom,
    required this.average_sales_tops,
    required this.average_sales_Bottoms,
  });

  Receiving copyWith({
    String? total_rec_top,
    String? total_rec_bottom,
    String? cur_month_top,
    String? cur_month_bottom,
    String? per_month_top,
    String? per_month_bottom,
    String? average_sales_tops,
    String? average_sales_Bottoms,
  }) {
    return Receiving(
      total_rec_top: total_rec_top ?? this.total_rec_top,
      total_rec_bottom: total_rec_bottom ?? this.total_rec_bottom,
      cur_month_top: cur_month_top ?? this.cur_month_top,
      cur_month_bottom: cur_month_bottom ?? this.cur_month_bottom,
      per_month_top: per_month_top ?? this.per_month_top,
      per_month_bottom: per_month_bottom ?? this.per_month_bottom,
      average_sales_tops: average_sales_tops ?? this.average_sales_tops,
      average_sales_Bottoms:
          average_sales_Bottoms ?? this.average_sales_Bottoms,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'total_rec_top': total_rec_top,
      'total_rec_bottom': total_rec_bottom,
      'cur_month_top': cur_month_top,
      'cur_month_bottom': cur_month_bottom,
      'per_month_top': per_month_top,
      'per_month_bottom': per_month_bottom,
      'average_sales_tops': average_sales_tops,
      'average_sales_Bottoms': average_sales_Bottoms,
    };
  }

  factory Receiving.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Receiving(
      total_rec_top: map['total_rec_top'],
      total_rec_bottom: map['total_rec_bottom'],
      cur_month_top: map['cur_month_top'],
      cur_month_bottom: map['cur_month_bottom'],
      per_month_top: map['per_month_top'],
      per_month_bottom: map['per_month_bottom'],
      average_sales_tops: map['average_sales_tops'],
      average_sales_Bottoms: map['average_sales_Bottoms'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Receiving.fromJson(String source) =>
      Receiving.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

This was generated using : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator

Then you can go ahead to do this:

```dart
Future<DashboardModel?> _getDashboard() async {
  try {
    var res = await http.post(API.get_dashboard2, body: parameters);
    final _dashboard = DashboardModel.fromJson(res.body);

    if (_dashboard.success == 1 && res.statusCode == 200) {
      return _dashboard;
    } else if (_dashboard.success == 0) {
      Toast.show(dashboard.message, context,
          gravity: Toast.BOTTOM, duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry but my environment:sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0" is this and it was asking me for 2.12.0 minimum sdk version